# COUNT the number of sales and display in listview C#

Tags: c#, sql

I have the following code that needs to list (within a ListView) each product, the product type and the number of customers that have purchased the product. I have tried this but it does not work.

I am not sure whether I need to create another Class and then define the list and what I need to include in the ListViewItems. I am new to C# coding but have been able to show data using similar methids but I have not been required to do calculations before. Any help would be appreciated. I can provide the files (Project and SQL) if required.

```
namespace Acme
{
public partial class frmMainForm : Form
{
    public frmMainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
     //Not sure if the following is correct//   
    private void DisplaySales()
    {
        string selectQuery;

        selectQuery = "SELECT Products.ProductName, ProductTypes.ProductType, COUNT(Sales.ProductID) as SALES,"; 
        selectQuery = selectQuery + "FROM Products INNER JOIN ProductTypes ON Products.ProductTypeID,";
        selectQuery = selectQuery + "ProductTypes.ProductTypeID INNER JOIN, ";
        selectQuery = selectQuery + "Sales ON Sales.ProductID = Products.ProductID GROUP BY Products.ProductName ";
        selectQuery = selectQuery + "ProductTypes.ProductType, Sales.ProductID";
        selectQuery = selectQuery + " " + GlobalVariables.salesSearchCriteria;

        SqlConnection conn = ConnectionManager.DatabaseConnection();
        SqlDataReader rdr = null;

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectQuery, conn);
            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {

                //Not sure if I need to create a seperate Class and then define the list (Class - ProductSales??)

                //Also need to include ListviewItems ??????

            }
            if (rdr != null)
                rdr.Close();
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unsuccessful" + ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You may find it worthwhile to read up on https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper .

Answer (score 1):

Create **Product** class, and get data like sample bellow

```
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    List<Product> lstProduct = new List<Product>();

    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Product product = new Product();
            product.ProductName = reader.GetString(0);
            ...
            lstProduct.add(product);
        }
    }

    // Do what you want with lstProduct
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to create another Class. Get your data through that queries and set to the data table and assign data table to Listview.